# step down transformer(240V-9V)

Tags: transformer, electrically-conductive

I Have step down transformer that transforms 240V to 9V.

However, I cannot find out, which terminals are for input and which are for output. The turn ratio size is very similar, because it is covered.

How can input and output side be identified?

Answer (score 2):

Measure resistance with an ohm-meter (e.g. DMM). The high-voltage winding will have much higher resistance because it uses thinner wire.

Answer (score 2):

Turn ratio can't be similar as N1:N2 = V1:V2, therefore

$$ N_{primary}= \frac{240}{9} \cdot N_{secondary}$$

It's relatively easy: primary has more turns and less current, therefore the primary winding is longer and thiner, while secondary is thicker and shorter - therefore if you measure the resistance, you will get lower resistance for secondary and higher resistance for primary.

Comment: ya..i mean primary & secondary turns are covered by using some kind of paper or polithene..so cant see the turns..physical size is much similar..